# SQL - Count idUser with different creationDate

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
ID / creationDate
2  / 2012-06-28 04:58:27
2  / 2012-07-10 14:26:51
2  / 2013-04-18 00:35:36
3  / 2012-07-02 16:47:00
4  / 2012-07-02 20:24:22
5  / 2012-07-03 00:32:17
6  / 2012-07-05 04:40:02
6  / 2012-07-06 18:17:08
6  / 2013-04-28 22:28:54
```

I would like to count the number of `ID` which have 2 or more different `creationDate`. In my example, I would like to have 2 (`ID` 2 and 6 have different `creationDate`).

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(DISTINCT creationDate)>1
```

Comment: what output did you get from your query?

Comment: What happens if you group by creation date and change count(ID) in the having?

Comment: You shouldn't keep questions open. Did any of the responses answered you question? If so please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT ID,COUNT(DISTINCT creationDate)'CT'
      FROM Table
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT creationDate) > 1
     )sub
```

If using an RDBMS that supports `SUM() OVER()` you could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT ID))OVER()
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT creationDate) > 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6fd3/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(ID) AS IDCnt, ID
    FROM table
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING count(ID)>1
    ) a
```